# Object ProductRequest is not supported in UI API

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am using following lightning code but unfortunately, I am getting error. Can anyone please help me to fix this (I read some articles and they mentioned that this object is not supported in UI API)

[image]

```
<aura:attribute name="editPR" type="ProductRequest" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'ProductRequest' }"/>
      <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
           <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" objectApiName="ProductRequest" >
                 <lightning:messages />
                 <lightning:inputField fieldName="{! v.ProductRequest.Ship_To_Home_or_Site_Address__c }" />
                 <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Update record" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
           </lightning:recordEditForm>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) supports objects as supported by the UI-API.

> This component doesn't support all Salesforce standard objects. For example, the Event and Task objects are not supported.
>
> For a list of supported objects, see the User Interface API Developer Guide.

The error message as it suggests that the object `ProductRequest` is not supported, that means you **cannot** use it in your component.

For a list of supported objects by UI-API, refer to this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm).

Comment: Thank you Jayant !!  Any alternate way to use that object in my lightning component to provide input fields ?

Comment: You can just use regular lightning:input component and manipulate the data as per your need. It’s just that you cannot use the edit form component.